# Notifications don’t disappear after clicking on them when using Chrome on iPhone

Tags: bug, notifications, ios, mobile-chrome

Notifications don’t disappear after clicking on them when using Chrome on iPhone. Example:

[image: mov to gif with https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif/]

I use an iPhone 12 mini with iOS 15. I don't have this issue with Chrome on Windows.